# Concrete Class inherit from Abstract class which inherits from Generic Abstract Class

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, c#-6.0

I'm an "old school" programmer here that is struggling with using inheritance to my advantage.  I found myself repeating code and it started to smell.  I wasn't adhering to DRY, so I'm trying to refactor a bit here to cut down on the code duplication!

I'm trying to write Value Object classes to be used in my Entities, which will enforce basic invariants.  I have a generic abstract ValueObject class that handles equality and hashes like so:

```
public abstract class ValueObject<T> where T : ValueObject<T>
{
    protected abstract IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityCheckAttributes();

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as T);
    }

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return GetEqualityCheckAttributes().SequenceEqual(other.GetEqualityCheckAttributes());
    }

    public static bool operator == (ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator != (ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        foreach (var obj in this.GetEqualityCheckAttributes())
        {
            hash = hash * 31 + (obj == null ? 0 : obj.GetHashCode());
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

I have been then creating my value object classes which then implement this abstract class, and provide the logic to make sure the object can't be created in an invalid state.  This is when I started violating DRY, and was creating many objects with the same code (e.g. required string with max length of 50 or 30 or 10).

So I wish to put the code that enforces the invariant in its own class, and have my concrete value object class inherit that capability.  Something like (this doesn't compile, see below):

```
public abstract class RequiredStringValueObject : ValueObject<string>
{
    private string _value;
    protected string _fieldName;
    protected byte _maxLength;

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(_fieldName, _fieldName + " must be supplied.");
            }
            value = value.Trim();
            if (value.Length > _maxLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(_fieldName, value, _fieldName + " can't be longer than " + _maxLength.ToString() + " characters.");
            }
            _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I could "use" all of this functionality in the concrete class like so:

```
public class FirstName : RequiredStringValueObject
{
    private FirstName(string value, string FieldName, byte MaxLength)
    {
        _fieldName = FieldName;
        _maxLength = MaxLength;
        Value = value;
    }
    public static FirstName Create(string value, string FieldName, byte MaxLength)
    {
        return new FirstName(value, FieldName, MaxLength);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityCheckAttributes()
    {
        return new List<object> { Value };
    }
}
```

All of this seems like a reasonable way to solve the problem (to me).  Problem is I'm getting a compiler error in the RequiredStringValueObject declaration:

> The type `string` cannot be used as a type parameter `T` in the generic type or method `ValueObject<T>`.  There is no implicit reference conversion from `string` to `ValueObject<string>`.

I don't understand the error message exactly.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?  Is there a way to make this work?  Or is there another approach I could/should be taking?

Comment: I am not sure, but why do you have the `where T : ValueObject<T>`

Comment: Error is due to how class is defined. You have `public abstract class ValueObject<T> where T : ValueObject<T>`. Essentially you're saying - I'm declaring a generic class with T being restricted to the instances of this very class. Sort of circular definition. `String` does not satisfy that criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from this line:

```
abstract class ValueObject<T> where T : ValueObject<T>
```

You are requiring `T` to inherit from `ValueObject<T>` so when you write:

```
RequiredStringValueObject : ValueObject<string>
```

`string` doesn't inherit from `ValueObject` (obviously) so you need to inherit from `ValueObject<ValueObject<string>>`, except that *also* violates the constraint and well... its turtles all the way down.

The easy fix is to remove the type constraint; it seems like your code is mostly set up for dealing with `object` any ways so you shouldn't need it. Putting any kind of "recursive" type constraint is just going to cause you problems in this setup. If you really need such a thing, you might need to go with composition instead, something like:

```
public interface IValueMethods<T>
{
   //required methods
}

//Constructor for value object
public ValueObject<T>(IValueMethods<T> commonMethods)
{
}
```

And then you can pass in the set of methods to use as a separate object.

Comment: Removing the constraint then trickles problems down in to my ValueObject abstract class.  In the Equals method, I then get "The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint."  So I change from 'other as T' to 'other as object'?

Comment: Also, other.GetEqualityCheckAttributes() then has issue: "'T' does not contain a definition for 'GetEqualityCheckAttributes' and no extension method 'GetEqualityCheckAtributes' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found"

Comment: @Scuzzlebutt you will likely have to rework `GetEqualityCheckAttributes` perhaps with the interface suggestion from above. As far as the first one, you can put a `where T : class` constraint but I seriously doubt you *want* that as it seems you would want it to work with int, short, etc.

Comment: Maybe restrict `T` to `IEquatable`?  It looks like you only perform "equal" type operations on it.  That filter would allow you to implement your comparisons through that interface.

Comment: Yea looks like I need to rework my ValueObject class a bit.  The equality checks aren't working correctly now.

Answer (score 4):

You have a where clause on your generic type T:

```
public abstract class ValueObject<T> where T : ValueObject<T>
```

This is telling the compiler that T must derive from ValueObject, and string does not.

What are you trying to enforce with that where T: clause?  You probably want to omit it.

Answer (score 2):

In agreement with what @BradleyDotNET said. A possible fix could look like following:

```
public abstract class ValueObjectBase
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityCheckAttributes();
}

public abstract class ValueObject<T> : ValueObjectBase where T : class
{
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other is ValueObjectBase)
            return Equals(other as ValueObjectBase);

        return Equals(other as T);
    }

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {

        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return other.Equals(this);

    }

    public bool Equals(ValueObjectBase other)
    {
        return GetEqualityCheckAttributes().SequenceEqual(other.GetEqualityCheckAttributes());
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        foreach (var obj in this.GetEqualityCheckAttributes())
        {
            hash = hash * 31 + (obj == null ? 0 : obj.GetHashCode());
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  Would have never thought of this on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of your help, here is the final working solution:

**ValueObject**

```
public abstract class ValueObjectBase
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityCheckAttributes();
}

public abstract class ValueObject<T> : ValueObjectBase
{
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other is ValueObjectBase)
        {
            return Equals(other as ValueObjectBase);
        }
        return Equals(other as IEquatable<T>);
    }

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return other.Equals(this);
    }

    public bool Equals(ValueObjectBase other)
    {
        return GetEqualityCheckAttributes().SequenceEqual(other.GetEqualityCheckAttributes());
    }

    public static bool operator == (ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator != (ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right)
    {
        return !(Equals(left, right));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        foreach (var obj in this.GetEqualityCheckAttributes())
        {
            hash = hash * 31 + (obj == null ? 0 : obj.GetHashCode());
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

A variation on the theme, the **RequiredStringValueObject**:

```
public abstract class RequiredStringValueObject : ValueObject<string>
{
    private string _value;
    protected string _fieldName;
    protected byte _maxLength;

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(_fieldName, _fieldName + " must be supplied.");
            }
            value = value.Trim();
            if (value.Length > _maxLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(_fieldName, value, _fieldName + " can't be longer than " + _maxLength.ToString() + " characters.");
            }
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    protected RequiredStringValueObject(string fieldName, byte maxLength, string value)
    {
        _fieldName = fieldName;
        _maxLength = maxLength;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityCheckAttributes()
    {
        return new List<object> { Value };
    }
}
```

And the concrete implementation, the **FirstName** (a required string based value object with maximum length):

```
 public class FirstName : RequiredStringValueObject
{
    private FirstName(string value) : base(nameof(FirstName),30, value) { }

    public static FirstName Create(string value)
    {
        return new FirstName(value);
    }

}
```

As a child of the 80's would say, "Totally tubular!"

Thanks!